# "Ĉionmanĝanta ŝafo" or "Ĉiomanĝanta ŝafo"? Can you build a word with the accusative like that?

Tags: word-formation, accusative

I want to build an adjective for a sheep that *eats everything*. I had the idea to put together the last part of the sentence "Ŝafo *manĝanta ĉion*", giving *ĉionmanĝanta*. However, this word is very uncommon, and *ĉiomanĝanta* gives many more results from Google. Why? I personally prefer *ĉionmanĝanta*, because with *ĉiomanĝanta* the *ĉio* can be the sheep.

Comment: I would use "manĝantema" for either of these methods, since the sheep is not eating all the time.

Comment: A sheep that eats everything is called a kapro.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In compound words, you only use the accusative form for *si*. (This is discussed in PAG §310.)

So the word you want is *ĉiomanĝ(ant)a*. Be aware that *ĉiovora* means *omnivorous*.

In PIV, under *ĉio*, these examples are given of *ĉio* as prefix:

> *ĉiofaranto (Dio), ĉiopardona<sup>Z</sup>, ĉiopova<sup>Z</sup>; ĉiovida, ĉioscia<sup>Z</sup>, ĉiovora; ĉiovendejo*
>
> all-doing (God), all-forgiving, all-powerful; all-seeing, all-knowing, omnivorous; department store
>
> omnific (God), omniremissive, omnipotent; omnipercipient, omniscient, omnivorous; department store

Comment: I've never seen "omnidimittent" or "omnipercipient" in my life, and my spell-checker doesn't recognize them. Perhaps simple "all-forgiving" and "all-seeing" would be preferable translations.

Comment: I don't find _omnipercipient_ on the _New Oxford American Dictionary_, nor on the _Oxford Dictionary of English_ too.

Comment: Althought, Wiktionary has an entry for [_omnipercipient_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/omnipercipient), but nothing for _omnidimittent_.